# Doubly linked list reverse print?

Tags: c++, linked-list, reverse, doubly-linked-list

I have to turn add a member function called "reversePrint" into this doubly linked list. And print out names reversely. 
For example, input:
Jason
Ryan
Dylan
Louie

Output should be:
Louie
Dylan
Ryan
Jason

My thought of getting this done is move all the way down to the end of the list first, namely the last node. Then use "Previous" pointer to go back to the previous nodes one at a time, at the same time print out the name. Therefore I will have a reversed print.
However, there is something wrong with my pointer I think, I just could not figure out how to fix it. Some helps are really appreciated!!!

**UPDATE: This code was originally singly linked. I tried to turn it into a doubly linked and add the "reversePrint" function. However I figure the problem is that, I did not modify the "Add" method right, so the "prev" pointers are disconnected. So any help that how to modify "Add" so I can make it into a fully doubly-linked-list?

This is the output it gives right now:
 prev 0x0
 address 0x100200000 data a
 next 0x100300000

prev 0x0
 address 0x100300000 data b
 next 0x100400000

prev 0x0
 address 0x100400000 data c
 next 0x0

This is the output we need:
 prev 0x0
 address 0x100200000 data a
 next 0x100300000

prev 0x100200000
 address 0x100300000 data b
 next 0x100400000

prev 0x100300000
 address 0x100400000 data c
 next 0x0

Following is my code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    // define a node for storage and linking
    class node{
    public:
        string name;
        node *next;
        node *prev; // to be implemented by students
    };

    class linkedList{
    public:
        linkedList():top(NULL){}
        bool empty(){return top == NULL;}
        node *getTop(){return top;}
        void setTop(node *n){top = n;}
        void add(string);
        int menu();
        void remove(string);
        ~linkedList();
        void reversePrint(); // to be implemented by students
        friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, const linkedList&); // default output   is in-order print.
    private:
        node *top;
        node *end; // to be used for reverse print and implemented by students
    };

    int main(void){
        linkedList l;
        //cout << l.empty() << endl;
        int option = 0;
        string s;
        bool go = true;
        while(go){
            option = l.menu();
            switch(option){
                case 1: cout << "enter a name: ";cin >> s; l.add(s); break;
                case 2: cout << "enter name to be deleted: "; cin >> s; l.remove(s);break;
                case 3: cout << l; break;
                case 4: l.reversePrint(); break;
                case 5: cout << "exiting" << endl; go = false; break;
            }
        }
        // l goes out of scope and calls ~linkedList()
        return(NULL);
    }
    // can not call this method "delete" - "delete" is a reserved keyword.
    void linkedList::remove(string s){
        bool found = false;
        node *curr = getTop(), *prev=NULL;
        while(curr != NULL){
            // match found, delete
            if(curr->name == s){
                found = true;
                // found at top
                if(prev == NULL){
                    node *temp = getTop(); // delete the current node(which is the head), and set the "new head" to as the next node
                    setTop(curr->next);
                    delete(temp);
                    // found in list - not top
                }else{
                    prev->next = curr->next; //Skip the current deleted node, connect previous node directly to the next node
                    delete(curr);
                } }
            // not found, advance pointers
            if(!found){
                prev = curr;
                curr = curr->next; }
            // found, exit loop
            else curr = NULL; }
        if(found)cout << "Deleted " << s << endl;
        else cout << s << " Not Found "<< endl; }


    void linkedList::add(string s){
        node *n = new node();
        n->name = s;
        n->next = NULL;
        // take care of empty list case
        if(empty()){ top = n;
            // take care of node belongs at beginning case
        } else if(getTop()->name > s)
        {
            n->next = getTop();
            setTop(n);
            // take care of inorder and end insert
        }else{
            // insert in order case
            node *curr = getTop(), *prev = curr;
            while(curr != NULL){
                if(curr->name > s)break;
                prev = curr;
                curr = curr->next;
            }
            if(curr != NULL){ // search found insert point
                n->next = curr;
                prev->next = n; }
            // take care of end of list insertion
            else if(curr == NULL){// search did not find insert point
                prev->next = n; }
        } }

    void linkedList::reversePrint(){
        node *curr = getTop(), *prev=NULL;
        // jump to the last node
        while(curr->next != NULL){
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr->next;

            //curr = curr->next;
            cout << "!!!!hahaha" << curr->name <<" Prev:" <<curr->prev << "    " << prev->name <<endl ;//testing purpose

        }

       //print the name then jump back to the previous node, stops at the first node which curr->prev = NULL
       while(prev != 0 ){
            cout << "NULL is not 0!";
            prev->prev = curr->next;
            //cout << curr->name;
            curr = prev;
        }


    }

    /*ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const linkedList& ll){
        //linkedList x = ll; // put this in and the code blows up - why?
        node *n = ll.top;
        if(n == NULL)cout << "List is empty." << endl;
        else
            while(n != NULL){
                os << n->name << endl;
                n = n->next;
            } return os;
    }*/
    ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const linkedList& ll){
        //linkedList x = ll; // put this in and the code blows up - why?
        node *n = ll.top;
        if(n == NULL)cout << "List is empty." << endl;
        else
            while(n != NULL){
                os << " prev " << n->prev << endl;
                os << " address " << n << " data " << n->name << endl;
                os << " next " << n->next << endl;
                n->prev = n;
                n = n->next;
            } return os;
    }

    // return memory to heap

    linkedList::~linkedList(){
        cout << "~linkedList called." << endl;
        node *curr = getTop(), *del;
        while(curr != NULL){
            del = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
            delete(del);
        }
    }

    int linkedList::menu(){
        int choice = 0;
        while(choice < 1 || choice > 5){
            cout << "\nEnter your choice" << endl;
            cout << " 1. Add a name." << endl;
            cout << " 2. Delete a name." << endl;
            cout << " 3. Show list." << endl;
            cout << " 4. Show reverse list. " << endl; // to be implemented by students
            cout << " 5. Exit. " << endl;
            cin >> choice;
        }
        return choice;
    }
```

Comment: How can that be your code?

Comment: It's just like the "forward printing". Only, start at the "tail" (vs. "head") and navigate by "previousNode" (vs. "nextNode"). If that doesn't work then the previous node pointer might not have been set correctly when creating the list.

Comment: I'm assuming what you have given us is your program's output?

Comment: LOL guys sorry I was trying to edit it...first post so...thanks for your timely comments tho..

Comment: don't downvote, he seems new here, may be while trying to format the question , he could not post the code correctly.

Comment: It's really helpful to post only the relevant parts of the code. In this case, It would have been most helpful to post the `reversePrint` function.

Comment: No precisely. I figure I have to modify "Add" method a little bit. The prev pointers r kinda messed up. U can see if u put it in the compiler

Comment: Linked lists are obsolete data structures.

Comment: @Mike: Are they? They can still be useful in certain places. If you don't need random access, they have really fast insertion / deletion and can be iterated through quickly.

Comment: @sFuller If you are calling new every time you insert something like above, insertion will not be really fast, it will be slow as hell in fact. If you are calling delete every time you remove (like above), deletion will be slow as hell too. Iterating a linked list? More like iterating a list of cache misses. The only useful implementation of a linked list would be one that manages its own dynamic memory pool, but at that point is it really even a linked list any more? Seems like something else entirely. I should have said vanilla linked lists are obsolete data structures.

Answer (score 2):

This looks problematic:

```
prev->prev = curr->next;
```

You are setting the previous node's previous node. You probably just want to set the previous node, right?

You probably want to do something like this:

```
while(curr != NULL)
{
    cout << curr->name;
    curr = curr->prev
}
```

Since by this point you have determined that `curr` is the last element in the list, you can now 'decrement' `curr` by assigning `curr` to it's previous element. Since the first element doesn't have a previous node, it's `prev` will be `NULL`. That way, the loop will stop when `curr` has been assigned to the previous element of the first element, which again, is `NULL`.

Comment: But if u put it in and see the output, u can see that the "prev" pointers are kinda disconnected. So I could not go back after I reached the last node. I figure I have to modify "Linkedlist::Add" a little bit to chain them up?

Comment: That's correct. Your add function should make sure that the `next` and `prev` pointers of the node last added and the new node point to the correct nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Your function add is invalid. Let for example consider the case when the list is empty. The following code snippet will correspond to this case.

```
void linkedList::add(string s){
    node *n = new node();
    n->name = s;
    n->next = NULL;
    // take care of empty list case
    if(empty()){ top = n;
        // take care of node belongs at beginning case
    } else if(getTop()->name > s)
```

As you can see data member end of the list was not set.

So you should be sure that function add works correctly before writing the realization of function reversePrint.

Comment: I dont understand, it seems like ur code is missing some part.

Comment: @user3103980, I think it is your task to write the missing code.

Comment: It seems like that what you did was simply deleted some of my code. Okay very helpful.